# How to switch android version in local repo?

Tags: android, git, tags, repository, git-checkout

I have downloaded whole working tree with the following command:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
repo sync -j8
```

After syncing successfully, I want to switch working tree to android 2.3.7.
You see I didn't specify branch with "-b" parameter when "repo init".
So I guess all tag info should be downloaded and I can easily switch to android 2.3.7 with the following command:

```
repo forall -c git checkout android-2.3.7_r1
```

But it produces many errors like:

```
error: pathspec 'android-2.3.7_r1' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

So how can I switch to android 2.3.7 without "repo init -b android-2.3.7_r1" and "repo sync"  again?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You cannot solve this problem using `repo forall`.

Lets assume for certainty that your current Android tree is clean - no local changes or commits, i.e. `repo status` shows nothing.

To properly switch Android version, all you need to change is branch for your manifest repository. First determine the available branches with manifests for the different Android versions:

```
cd $ANDROID_ROOT
cd .repo/manifests
git branch -av   # see all available branches on origin
```

Select a version and

```
cd $ANDROID_ROOT
repo init -b <my_selected_android_version>
```

Such selective `repo init` with `-b` (without `-u`) will only update manifest branch and will not otherwise touch your tree.

Now, simply sync it:

```
repo sync
```

and some time later, your Android tree will switch to another version.

Speed of this operation is mostly determined by how much `default.xml` manifest file differs between old and new Android versions - because if some git repository was added in new manifest, it will spend time cloning it. And if some repository was removed, if will actually blow it away.

But, by and large, this method is still much faster than initializing brand new Android tree from scratch.

Comment: After reading your post, I realized that I have misunderstood some key aspects of git/repo. Thank you very very much!

Comment: It seems repo has changed, is `.repo/manifest` now `.repo/manifests`?

Answer (score 1):

if the branch you are in and the branch you will switch to has the same manifest.xml file, then you can use the following commands to do that.

```
repo forall -c git fetch aosp --tags 
repo forall -c git checkout -b john5.1.1_r14_api22 android-5.1.1_r14
```

also see details in
http://johnliao52.github.io/2016/03/27/git-repo-skills.html

Comment: Thanks for the useful documentation in Chinese